# Plugins don't work on xcode 6

Tags: plugins, xcode6

Yeah, we have a new xcode version - xcode 6 and all old plugins don't work.

I know there is a new **DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs** for each Xcode version and this problem will be fixed by plugin authors.

But DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs is just a text, how can we find it? How can we fix without waiting for someone

**Update**

xcode 6.3.2: DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs = E969541F-E6F9-4D25-8158-72DC3545A6C6

XCode 6.4 (6E35b): DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs = 7FDF5C7A-131F-4ABB-9EDC-8C5F8F0B8A90

XCode 7.0.b2 (7A121I): DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs = AABB7188-E14E-4433-AD3B-5CD791EAD9A3

Comment: - XCode 6.4 (6E35b): DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs = 7FDF5C7A-131F-4ABB-9EDC-8C5F8F0B8A90
 - XCode 7.0.b2 (7A121I): DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs = AABB7188-E14E-4433-AD3B-5CD791EAD9A3

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Make sure your hidden folders are shown on your MAC ,
Hold Option Key and click on Go option in finder menu.

Go to Following Location -

library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins

Right click on the plug in and select show package contents

Open the info.plist file and find the DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs and expand that section.

Click the + button and paste the C4A681B0-4A26-480E-93EC-1218098B9AA0 .

Save the file and restart Xcode.

No Need to repeat for all plugins that are already installed to Xcode 6.

Comment: this link: library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins

: ~/?ibrary/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins

is no longer working

Comment: ```/Developer``` in Xcode 6+ is all contained within the Xcode.app. The new location is ```/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer```.

Comment: ~/Library/Application\ Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/

Answer (score 1):

I have Xcode 6.1.1, here's what I did and it worked.

1. Right click on plugin file > **Show Package Contents**
2. Find and edit the **Info.plist** file.
3. In **DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs** add the key C4A681B0-4A26-480E-93EC-1218098B9AA0 (thanks to amavi message)

Save your Info.plist file.

Then go to */Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns* folder, and copy your plugin file there (the administrator password will be required).

You can now launch Xcode and use your plugins ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Run below command in Terminal. It will auto add Xcode's compatible UUID to all plugins:

```
find ~/Library/Application\ Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins -name Info.plist -maxdepth 3 | xargs -I{} defaults write {} DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs -array-add `defaults read /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Info.plist DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUID`
```

Answer (score 0):

From https://gist.github.com/neonichu/9487584 use the following to get the DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUID of your Xcode version

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c 'Print DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUID' "$(xcode-select -p)/../Info.plist"
```

For Xcode 6.2 add A16FF353-8441-459E-A50C-B071F53F51B7 to DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs

Answer (score 0):

xCode 6.3.2 was E969541F-E6F9-4D25-8158-72DC3545A6C6

I just check the plugins from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns (Any plugin and use what they use for DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUID) and it works.

Adding more info:

The Path is to xCode app itself and within it go to Contents/PlugIns folder and you will see a bunch of plugins for xCode. Open any plugin package and go to Contents of it and open Info.plist, which will have the property DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs. I did compare a couple of them and they seem to have the same so i copied that and used it which worked just fine.

Comment: Can you detail your answer to the OP's questions: "DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs is just a text, how can we find it? How can we fix without waiting for someone?" Is the path you have given the location of `DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs` (edit your answer please)?

Comment: Sorry for late reply was on a trip.

The Path is to xCode app itself and within it go to Contents/PlugIns folder and you will see a bunch of plugins for xCode. Open any plugin package and go to Contents of it and open Info.plist, which will have the property DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs.

Answer (score 0):

- XCode 6.4 (6E35b): DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs = 7FDF5C7A-131F-4ABB-9EDC-8C5F8F0B8A90
- XCode 7.0.b2 (7A121I): DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs = AABB7188-E14E-4433-AD3B-5CD791EAD9A3